# how to fix this strange effect when editing image?

Tags: image-processing, camera

G'day,

I have this strange effect when editing my image. It seems to happen a lot on photos with the sky in it, but in the CR2 file it doesn't show, only when i open it in the software i am using does it appear.

[image]

Comment: Is the image overexposed at these places (i.e. very close to white) ? That makes me think of a*b* components incorrectly handled in case of saturation.

Comment: "the software i am using" -> which software are you using?